# How to use MongoDB aggregate in Moleculer

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, moleculer, moleculer-web

I am new to moleculer framework. I want to use MongoDB's aggregate with moleculer framework it is possible ?
Can anybody tell me how to write MongoDb's aggregate query in moleculer framework.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use mongoDB aggregate in moleculer, You just have to use MongoDB Adapter in mixins of the service as given in samples given in [link to moleculer-db-adapter-mongo](https://github.com/moleculerjs/moleculer-db/tree/master/packages/moleculer-db-adapter-mongo). Then in any action of that service you can access any methods like aggregate, find, count, etc as `this.adapter.collection.aggregate([your aggregate query])`.